# Auto-generated UserID in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have created a function to generate UserID.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

FUNCTION `studentinformation_db`.`FX_AUTOGENERATEDID`()
RETURNS  VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8

BEGIN
    SET @cut = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(`ID`,13)) FROM `students`);
    SET @max = (SELECT @cut  + 1);
    SET @id = CONCAT('USERID',DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m%d%y'),@max);
    RETURN  @id ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but my problem is after it reaches 
USERID03151810

**Error**

> Error Code: 1062
>       Duplicate entry 'USERID03151810' for key 'PRIMARY'

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Use timestamp instead of current date

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have two issues here.

The reason you get the maximum value of 10 is because you are using the MAX() function on the **strings** returned by SUBSTRING(). When comparing strings '9' is greater than '10'.

e.g.

For numerical comparison

```
SELECT 9 > 10;
+--------+
| 9 > 10 |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```

but for strings

```
SELECT '9' > '10';
+------------+
| '9' > '10' |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

If we assume you already have ID 'USERID03151510' and all the other records 1 through 9 for this date (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65b651) then MAX() will return '9'. This string will then be implicitly cast to a number when you add 1 to it in the next statement.

e.g.

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(`ID`,13)) FROM test.students;
+-------------------------+
| MAX(SUBSTRING(`ID`,13)) |
+-------------------------+
| 9                       |
+-------------------------+
```

You need to explicitly cast it to a number

e.g.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`ID`,13) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM students;
+-------------------------------------------+
| MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`ID`,13) AS UNSIGNED)) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                        10 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

The second, more subtle, issue is to do with the use of MAX() rather than a much simpler COUNT(). Looking at your format ('USERID' + DATE + NUMBER), I'm assuming you want to increment the numbers starting at 1 each day. However, your SELECT doesn't restrict itself to just today's records and will assign @cut with the highest value assigned on ANY day. If on your first day you create 11 rows, you will start numbering from 12 the next day. Essentially, you've created your own AUTO_INCREMENT field.

To get the number per day you need to change the SELECT to identify today's records. Using MAX() you'd need something like

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`ID`,13) AS UNSIGNED)),0)
FROM `students` 
WHERE SUBSTRING(`ID`,1,12) = 
  CONCAT('USERID',DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m%d%y'));
```

but you'd have avoided the numbering problem completely if you'd just used the much simpler COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `students` WHERE 
SUBSTRING(`ID`,1,12) = CONCAT('USERID',DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m%d%y'));
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation sir, I really appreciate it a lot. this really helps